# Cant load cookie data to another page

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to retrieve cookie data that has been set from another page but i cant seem to view that data, but if i fetch it in same page it will work

I have tried some methods but its still not working even after i refresh the cookies from the browser

This is code from the **add.php** page

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />
</form> 

if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE["shopping_cart"])) {
        $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']);

        $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
    } else {
        $cart_data = array();
    }

    $item_id_list = array_column($cart_data, 'item_id');

    if(in_array($_POST["hidden_id"], $item_id_list)) {
        foreach($cart_data as $keys => $values) {
            if($cart_data[$keys]["item_id"] == $_POST["hidden_id"]) {
                $cart_data[$keys]["item_quantity"] = $cart_data[$keys]["item_quantity"] + $_POST["quantity"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        $item_array = array(
                  'item_id'   => $_POST["hidden_id"],
                  'item_name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                  'item_price'  => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                   'item_quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
                  );
        $cart_data[] = $item_array;
    }


    $item_data = json_encode($cart_data);
    setcookie('shopping_cart', $item_data, time() + (86400 * 30),'/');
    header("location:show.php");
}
```

This is the code for retrieving cookie data from **add.php**,this code is another page called **show.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["shopping_cart"])) {
    $total = 0;
    $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']);
    $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);

    foreach($cart_data as $keys => $values){
?>  

        <p> <?php echo   $values["item_id"];?></p> 
        <p> <?php echo   $values["item_quantity"];?></p> 
        <p> <?php echo   $values["item_name"];?></p> 
        <p> <?php echo   $values["item_body"]; ?></p> 

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

All i want to do is to get the cookie data that is been set from the add page to be displayed on the show page

Comment: You should check your error log; you probably get warnings like `headers already sent` as you are outputting html before you set the cookie and try to do a redirect. You should not output anything before setting headers and cookies.

Comment: Can you make sure the cookie is being stored in your browser?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @jeroen thank you it works

Comment: I think you would be better to use SESSION instead of Cookies

Comment: @RiggsFolly i want to create a simple add to cart function, if the user is not logged in they can still add to cart via cookies can i preform the same task with sessions

Comment: Yes, you dont have to be logged in to use the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting the header first then set your cookie

Like this:

```
  header("location:show.php");  
  setcookie('shopping_cart', $item_data, time() + (86400 * 30),'/');
```